# Is there any word to describe a person that likes to travel a lot?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there any accurate word to describes a person that likes to travel a lot? I'm looking for something synonymous with *travel obsessed*.

Example:

> I am crazy about travel, I am a complete _________.

Comment: What is "obsessed travel"?

Comment: Also, you have used the right tags but not taken any notice of the checklists in the tag info (again). Please do that.

Comment: ***Travelholic*** is a neologism that appears to be gainig  traction. It means "addicted to travel": http://travel.cnn.com/pros-and-perils-being-travelholic-941106/

Comment: @Andrew, could u help me with that??

Comment: @Minz You need to add an example usage sentence to your post along with the research you've performed trying to determine a good word.

Comment: I have added, is it sufficient or more information would be required???

Comment: It's enough to undo my unilateral hold, but the tag info contains lots of hints on how to write a good question, including how you will judge what is "perfect". How do people who answer know what sort of word you are looking for?

Comment: [Peripatetic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peripatetic) means, basically, "traveling about", and is often used to describe an occupation or lifestyle.

Comment: Explorer or Frequent Flyer.

Comment: *Peripatetic* might work.

Comment: Nomad? Travel obsessed would be wanderlust,I think.

Comment: "they call me the **wanderer**, yeah the wanderer.."

Comment: peripatetic is an adjective, except in French. :) What wrong with travel nut?

Comment: Why do we need one word when two are better?

Comment: "Peripatetic" is often used in this sense.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps a bit old fashioned, a **globetrotter** is a passionate/inveterate traveller.

*For example, "To fund their journey, many globetrotters decide to find casual jobs abroad"*.

Answer (score 4):

Depending upon how you travel, you have a few options. A ["**vagabond**"](http://thefreedictionary.com/vagabond) is someone who travels from place to place, but with the implication that they do not have a permanent home to go back to. A "[**rover**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rover)" is one who roves from place to place, synonymous with ***wanderer***, but this may be easily confused with the more modern definition of rover, as in the mars or lunar rovers. The word "[**nomad**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nomad)" would likely be best understood by the general public for the meaning you desire. While it literally refers to a person who has no fixed home and moves from place to place, as with the nomads of the Mongolian steppes, it is commonly used to refer to someone who goes from place to place. All of these words, however, have connotations of having no permanent home; in place of a noun, it may work better for you to say that you have "[**wanderlust**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wanderlust)", or an urge to travel.

Comment: Thanks, Now m spoilt for choice, Can i use "Nomad" to describe if someone is passionate/Crazy about traveling?

Comment: For that I would use rover, or say they have wanderlust

Answer (score 3):

You can call such a person a *travel enthusiast* or for more impact, a ***travel freak***.

> I am crazy about travel, I am a complete ***travel
>   freak***.

Infoplease:

> **[freak](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/freak)**
>   *-n.*
>   **6**. *Slang*. 
>   **a**. a person who has withdrawn from normal, rational behavior and activities to pursue one interest or obsession: *a drug freak.* 
>   **b**. a devoted fan or follower; enthusiast: *a baseball freak.*

Comment: But this is two words.

Answer (score 3):

Peri- is the Greek word for "around," and peripatetic is an adjective that describes someone who likes to walk or travel around.

Peripatetic is also a noun for a person who travels from one place to another or moves around a lot.

SO..

**Peripatetic**

> If someone has a peripatetic life or career, they travel around a lot, living or working in places for short periods of time.

[_Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/peripatetic)

...works here.

Comment: Hi Sue, welcome to EL&U. Good word: you're halfway there! Note that an answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*, whereas yours is a bit on the thin side. I'd encourage you to [edit] your answer - for example, adding a published definition (linked to the source). For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Wanderlust](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wanderlust) is the yearning for far-off places.  German has the word, [Fernweh](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fernweh#German), or `farsickness`, the opposite of *homesickness*.  Farsickness is a snynonym of `wanderlust`.

Since the state of being is a kind of obsession, or `mania`, you could refer to them as a `maniac` of some sort.

However, I don't think there is any [existing term](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/people-who-are-ill-or-have-a-medical-condition) for this kind of `maniac`.  Perhaps we could assemble a *neologos* from the variables?

- `wanderlust` + `maniac` doesn't sound right together.
- `fernweh` + `maniac` do not seem to go together.  `fernwemaniac`?

What about referring to the person as `the wanderlustful` or `the farsick`?

> With ther uncontrollable longing for imagined sights, the **farsick** could 
>       not remain at home.  They were the **wanderlustful** who would not be detained.

Or we could just make up something that sounds nice.

- How about `wanderling`?  (I kind of like this one.)
- `fernwehling`  or `fernweling`
- `farling`
- `dreamling` - since wishing is similar to dreaming
- `wandrist` - wander-ist  (like peace is to pacifist)

> The **wanderling** glanced around at his sullen home, took up his daypack and triumphantly marched out the front door into the sunny horizon.

Answer (score 2):

I am crazy about travel, I am a complete

"**NOMAD**".

> A person who does not stay long in the same place; a wanderer.

[-OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nomad)

Comment: NO NEED TO USE ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 1):

Wayfarer : a traveler especially on foot

Examples of wayfarer in a Sentence:
One of the great wayfarers of American folklore, Johnny Appleseed wandered across the country, always planting apple seeds.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wayfarer

Comment: A pretty word but does not fit the bill...

Answer (score 1):

**Jetsetter**

More of a slang word, derived from the phrase "Jet Set"

> **Jet Set**
>
> noun:
>   a fashionable social set composed of wealthy people who travel frequently by jetliner to parties and resorts.
>
> Other words from "Jet Set"
>   jet-set·ter, noun
>
> (Dictionary.com)

It is implied that they "like" to travel a lot, or at the very least, travel a great amount in a glamorous way that sets fads.

Answer (score 1):

Peripatetic might be the word you are looking for.

Comment: You should include a dictionary reference and definition for your chosen word.

Answer (score 0):

The OP might be able to call him/her self an ***explorer***.  Even today, when every square meter has been mapped from space, there are things to explore from graffiti to fusion cusisines to changing -- and rigid -- customs to how ecosystems and the creatures in them are responding to the stresses of human activity.

The short definition of **explorer**, from [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/explorer) is:

> a person who travels to places where no one has ever been to learn
>   about them.

That is too restrictive a definition.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/explorer) is better

> one that explores; especially a person who travels in search of
>   geographical or scientific information

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66670?redirectedFrom=explorer#eid) has the best definition for the purposes of this answer:

> b. A person who examines, investigates or studies something

To be an *explorer*, you must go where few other travelers go and *not* on a packaged tour.    I'll use northern Europe as an example. Yes, you can go to Copenhagen and Stockholm and Oslo.  But you also must stay in Tromso in the far north of Norway in the middle of winter, live with the Lapps as they live for several weeks, tour the Global Seed Storage Vault in Svalbard, and, if you are physically capable and experienced, hike Kungsleden.  Wangling a volunteer slot on a scientific survey or with a group working with recent refugees would also be the mark of an explorer.

All three definitions say that the explorer is in search of information.  The modern explorer may or may not have a specific focus in mind when she sets out  Even if she doesn't have a purpose at the beginning, if she is an explorer, that focus will be developing, however slowly, during the course of her travels.

I'm not giving links to any of these places, because an explorer will do his own research, map out his own routes and learn the essential words and phrases of the local languages (although in Scandinavia it will be hard to find someone who does not speak English).  I'd better stop, but one more thought: an explorer takes pictures that are actually interesting to other people, i.e., no (or very few) selfies.

Answer (score 0):

a complete travel nut [slang] or a travel enthusiast [nicey, nicey]

> [big travel nut](http://bigtravelnut.com/)

Merriam Webster says: an enthusiast'

Another term that can be used. I have supplied nouns here.

Answer (score 0):

**[rolling stone](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rolling%20stone)**

> a person who changes his habitation, business, or pursuits with great frequency : one who leads a wandering or unsettled life (Merriam-Webster)

(refers to *A rolling stone gathers no moss*)

Some other possibilities: *globetrotter, rover, drifter, passionate traveler, travel addict* and the Spanish word *golondrina* (swallow).  Also *travel bug* (meaning you've been bitten by the travel bug). You could select any animal known for migrating, such as the emperor penguin. You could adjust your sentence a bit to get

> I am crazy about travel, I *live to travel*.

Best of all, in my opinion, would be to set up your sentence to use the adjective **restless**.

Comment: 'Rolling stone' is not used for someone who likes to see other places, but rather for someone who doesn't stay in one place. More in reference to lack of stability than to wanderlust.

Answer (score 0):

How about travelnut, one word? From MW:

Definition of traveling nut:

> a nut that travels on a revolving screw

Is it more nuts to travel alone or not to travel at all? Banner on a web site, Big Travel Nut

See also https://travelnutvacations.com/

Also, defining nut:

> Slang. a person who is very enthusiastic about something; buff; enthusiast; devotee: He's a real circus nut. an extremely concerned or zealous person: My boss is a nut on double-checking everything.

From dictionary.com › browse › nut

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying to use root words to come up with something I use ped for walking, and then I remembered there's a word called audiophile meaning someone who loves to collect music. You cannot combine these to make the word pedophile. But my thought is that you want something similar. Without the same punch that I feel that you want to pack, I can offer the words travel enthusiast. You might say trip hoarder